# Python : Event Based Sequence depended on Each other

Tags: python, if-statement, optimization, python-requests

I have a sequence of request calls dependent on each other, each one searches on a field in DB or Scrape a website, the sequence stops when a request finds the item

I am using a sequence of if statement pseudo code

```
if found: 
   return 
else:
   call_request(params1)

if found: 
   return 
else:
   call_second_request(params2)
```

I am looking for an optimized way to do this sequence of request calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the request functions inside a list and use a `for` loop:

```
request_funcs = [call_request, call_second_request, ...]

for func in request_funcs:
    result = func()
    if result:
        return
print("Not found")
```

If it's the same function, use a `while` loop:

```
found = False
while not found:
    found = call_next_request()
return
```

Comment: Thanks , Can I add parameters in the request_funcs. Different functions to be called each time

Comment: Worked with parameters fine 

Comment: @ahmedosama I'm glad I could help. If my solution has solved your problem, please be free to click the checkmark next to it and [accept it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). This lets other users know that your question was solved and awards us both a reputation bonus.